# How to determine number of instances for resources in a resource allocation graph?

Tags: resource-allocation

I am struggling to determine the number of instances a resource will have. I have performed extensive research on this, but unfortunately have come up short. I am tasked with drawing a resource allocation graph and I have been provided with the number of processes which is 3 and the of resources which is 5. I have concluded that when drawing the resource allocation graph, I will need to know the number of instances of a resource. Please could someone just help in how I would go about working out or determining the number of instances a resource will have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of instances should technically be specified to you. The best I can suggest is assume that each resource will only have one instance each. But I suggest getting more information on your scenario

Comment: Thanks for your response, this really help. I asked and they said it is 1. :)

Comment: Glad I could help